# ASP .NET MVC 5 - Decrease the left hand margin

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

I have created a new ASP .NET MVC application in VS2015 using the default template.  My index views are used the default shared _Layout file.

The issue is that the views all have excessive left hand margins with data being pushed off screen on the right.

How can I modify the CSS (bootstrap?) to reduce the left hand margin?

[image]

**Update1:**

Per the hint from Aravind.

I opened boostrap.css and then modified the css property .pull-left and commented out the float code:

```
.pull-left {
  /*float: left !important;*/
}
```

**Update2**

Per another hint from @Steven B

Went into _Layout.cshtml and edited to show:

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Penske Logistics</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: One option is to change your `.container` to `.container-fluid` to achieve a full-width layout without messing with the predefined grid system.  [Example](http://www.bootply.com/xXoWuQDVJJ).

Comment: @lamelemon - is the .container-fluid part of the default boostrap.css stylesheet?

Comment: Yes it's a class in bootstrap. [Here's](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) an overview of the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **pull-left** class as

```
<div class="pull-left"> Application Name </div>
```

Comment: @Aravind is there any tick that could do pull left with some padding... bz pull  left just sticks it way too left

Comment: @singhswat what actually you are looking for

Comment: I'm looking for 'Pull left with left padding of 20px' so there is same space left on the extreme left of the corner. Image url for reference http://pasteboard.co/3rzXgJ0UW.png

Comment: Note that @lamelemon's comment to the original post resolves this problem as well. I tend to shy away from modifying core layout files because it becomes a maintenance issue as new versions arrive.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try renaming your div to something outside of a bootstrap feature. Instead of using `container`, use `main`.

```html
<div class="main">Application Name</div>
```

This should give you the full width of the page as well